# I get the following failures on some devices

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

help! I get the following failures on some devices.

java.lang.Error  a.a.a.a.b.N.a

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
    Unity version     : 2017.4.35f1
    Device model      : samsung SM-N950F
    Device fingerprint: samsung/greatltexx/greatlte:9/PPR1.180610.011/N950FXXS8DSL3:user/release-keys
    Caused by
      at a.a.a.a.b.N.a (SourceFile:38)
      at a.a.a.a.b.K.shouldOverrideUrlLoading (SourceFile:1)
      at android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebViewClient.java:77)
      at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading (PG:16)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:326)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:181)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7073)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: Edit: Sorry, missunderstood the error log. Seems that a class isn't being found at your game. Can you please post some of the code where this error is happening?

Comment: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.VIBRATE, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Just edited the comment. Update the question and provide some code where you're getting this error please. And thx for the permissions list even if at the end it wasn't needed.

Comment: 02-12 14:49:46.126: E/Unity(5804): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "perf-events.cloud.unity3d.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: 02-12 14:50:20.236: E/Unity(5804): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "cdp.cloud.unity3d.com": No address associated with hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided at the comments section seems that you're having a very common error due editor statistics collection.

[Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unable-to-resolve-host-cdp-cloud-unity3d-com.498365/#post-5209445) you have a fix for it (disabling those statistics seems to solve the problem, as stated by the user who posted the comment at Unity Forum). Also, if you aren't using latest Unity version (and your project allows you to), try to update Unity to latest version as this error may be fixed in a latest version of Unity.

Hope this helps you!

P.S: If you try to update your Unity version remember to create a backup of the project.